# Making a button for a new activity

Tags: android, button, android-activity

I am creating my first app and I am trying to make a button that will take the user to the next activity. I researched around on how to do this and found a video that I followed (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fFOPzmeknNo). I don't seem to have any problems until I try to run it on an emulator. On the emulator it says the app has stopped working.  In the logcat I get this.

```
04-10 22:10:10.918: D/AndroidRuntime(1974): Shutting down VM
04-10 22:10:10.918: W/dalvikvm(1974): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2ae0ba8)
04-10 22:10:10.938: E/AndroidRuntime(1974): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-10 22:10:10.938: E/AndroidRuntime(1974): Process: com.example.first, PID: 1974
04-10 22:10:10.938: E/AndroidRuntime(1974): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.first/com.example.first.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-10 22:10:10.938: E/AndroidRuntime(1974):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
04-10 22:10:10.938: E/AndroidRuntime(1974):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
04-10 22:10:10.938: E/AndroidRuntime(1974):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
04-10 22:10:10.938: E/AndroidRuntime(1974):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
04-10 22:10:10.938: E/AndroidRuntime(1974):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-10 22:10:10.938: E/AndroidRuntime(1974):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-10 22:10:10.938: E/AndroidRuntime(1974):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
04-10 22:10:10.938: E/AndroidRuntime(1974):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-10 22:10:10.938: E/AndroidRuntime(1974):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-10 22:10:10.938: E/AndroidRuntime(1974):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
04-10 22:10:10.938: E/AndroidRuntime(1974):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
04-10 22:10:10.938: E/AndroidRuntime(1974):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-10 22:10:10.938: E/AndroidRuntime(1974): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-10 22:10:10.938: E/AndroidRuntime(1974):     at com.example.first.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:27)
04-10 22:10:10.938: E/AndroidRuntime(1974):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
04-10 22:10:10.938: E/AndroidRuntime(1974):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
04-10 22:10:10.938: E/AndroidRuntime(1974):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
04-10 22:10:10.938: E/AndroidRuntime(1974):     ... 11 more
```

I have looked around but have been unable to find a solution. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

My on create method (I hope)

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    play = (Button)findViewById(R.id.play);
    play.setOnClickListener(this);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
    }
}

private void playClick()
{
    startActivity(new Intent("this,Maps.class"));
}
```

Not sure if this is exactly what your looking for but I hope it helps.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId())
    {
    case R.id.play:
        playClick();
        break;
    }
```

Comment: Post the onCreate method of MainActivity and your XML. You have a NullPointerException in line 27.

Comment: can you tell me what is code for `MainActivity.java:27` ?

Comment: Did you add your button inside `activity_main` or `fragment_main`?

Comment: My button is in the fragment_main.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put your button inside your `onCreateView` method. Because it's the fragment layout which is concerned. These lines:

```
play = (Button)findViewById(R.id.play);
play.setOnClickListener(this);
```

need to be into your fragment. But firstly, remove the `implement OnClickListener` on your activity:

```
implements OnClickListener {..}
```

Then, find your button into your Fragment and call the new activity:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

    // Here, you will find these views with its ids 
    play = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.play);

    // DON'T FORGET TO ATTACH THE VIEWS TO THE INFLATED VIEW
    // HERE IT'S "rootView.findViewById(R.id...)"  

    play.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // do your stuff
        }  
    });
}
```

Also, your `Intent` have an error: you cannot use a String like *"myclass.this, second.class"*... You should use the name class (without quotation marks) as follows:

```
// First the activity where you are now, second the activity class you want to go
startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Maps.class));
```

However, into a Fragment you need to attach the parent activity as `getActivity()`:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // Attach the parent and go to Maps activity
    startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), Maps.class));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you get null pointer, while you try to bring your curent activity to another activity with this code :

```
startActivity(new Intent("this,Maps.class"));
```

to bring your curent activity to another activity, you shouldn't put `"` as below :

```
startActivity(new Intent(this,Maps.class));
```

Comment: I got rid of the " however it does not seem to have had any effect.

Answer (score 0):

firstly you have to create a private button variable out side oncreate method.

```
  private Button play.
```

then add this code in oncreate method. 
  your current class is your java class name

```
play= (Button) findViewById(R.id.play);
play.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Intent intent_map = new Intent(yourcurrentclass.this, Maps.class);
                startActivity(intent_home);
                finish();

        }
    });
```